# cakePHP saving All data with hasMany function

Tags: cakephp

Hi Im just wondering if it is possible to save multiple data that has hasMany: and if it is possible what is the array structure before executing $this->Model->saveAll($this->data).

example is that you are going to save multiple posts at a time like this:

```
array(
    [Post] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => title One
                [content] => desc One
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => title two
                [content] => desc two
            )

    )
```

So in the given array above we can save all the Post with saveAll but what if each Post have hasMany comment each. how the array should look like if i have to insert the array below:

```
array(
    [Comment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [comment] => 1st Comment for Post One
            )


        [1] => Array
            (
                [comment] => 2nd Comment for Post One
            )


        [2] => Array
            (
                [comment] => 1st Comment for Post Two
            )


        [3] => Array
            (
                [comment] => 2nd Comment for Post Two
            )

    )
```

How can I combine the two array to execute saveAll();
Thanks in advance. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the association for "post has many comments" is called `"Comments"`, the data would look something like

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'title1',
            'content' => 'content1',
            'Comments' => array(
                array('comment'=>'1st comment for post 1'),
                array('comment'=>'2nd comment for post 1'),
            ),
        array(
            'title' => 'title2',
            'content' => 'content2',
            'Comments' => array(
                array('comment'=>'1st comment for post 2'),
                array('comment'=>'2nd comment for post 2'),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

To save you could use something like:

```
$this->Model->saveMany($data, array('deep'=>TRUE));
```

Note that the "deep" option requires CakePHP 2.1. Without it the associated Comment records would not be saved.

All this is documented in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html